# throughput in jmeter convert inkb/s

Tags: jmeter, throughput

how do you calculate the throughput in jmter?
and how to convert it to Kb / s?
[summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6M9R.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the throughput in kilobytes per second already?

[image]

JMeter automatically stores sent and received bytes into .jtl result files therefore total throughput will be the sum of `bytes` and `sentBytes` columns:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Calculator Class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java)

Also don't run your tests in GUI mode, it's for only tests development and debugging, when it comes to test execution [you should be running JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) and once test execution is finished you can analyze the results using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) (use "Browse" button to locate .jtl results file) of your choice or generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)